# How to copy code to online IDEs where copy and paste is disabled?

Tags: python-3.x, copy-paste

I referred the net, and finally wrote this code which helps in copying and pasting any piece of multi-line string.
Here's the code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
keybrd = Controller()
time.sleep(2)
# Here goes the code
code ='''

'''

for char in code:
    keybrd.press(char)
    keybrd.release(char)
```

It works perfectly on notepads, or other standalone offline editors.

However, on online IDEs, the output, i.e. the pasted code is often erroneously spaced, quite randomly, and I often found some weird words, in between. And the pasting process, pastes all the code in one single line only. On online IDEs, it can't create newlines.

Please help me out here.

Comment: Does keybrd.type(code) works?

Comment: No, it doesn't imitates it in the given structure. This, unlike, what I did, earlier, doesn't pastes in one single line, but does so, in an erratically indented manner.

Comment: Those IDEs probably have their own rule for code formattings. For example, pasting your code as is to Stackoverflow will result in ugly code all over. Can you point out a specific site in your question where we can reproduce the result?

Comment: @Martheen I tried a java code on [link](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051705/00000000000881da) , and actually, it doesn't works on Sublime Text also.

Comment: How about adding a random delay between each keypress?